# Is worth change databases collation from Latin1_General to Modern spanish, migrating to a new server

Tags: sql-server, collation

We are migrating 3 databases tables from Sql Server 2000 to a new sqlserver 2014.

I know that for new databases the recommended Collation for spanish is Modern_Spanish. But what is the recommendation for migrating database to a new server? Create the new server with the same collation of the 3 Databases (Latin1_General)? Or migrate the current dabases to Modern_Spanish.

The current sql server 2000 where the 3 databases are running the default collati is Latin1_General as the 3 database.

Is it worth to create the new server with Modern Spanish collation, and migrate databases collation to Modern Spanish? Or it's better to continue with Latin1_General ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you having problems with the sort order in the current system ? If not keep the collation. If the sort order is troubling users you should use the opportunity to change it during migration. You have to make certain that the collection change will not break user applications and queries so you will have to test your applications which will add time to the migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern_Spanish and Latin1_General both support the same character set. The difference between the two is the treatment of certain characters when sorting/doing comparisons. For example in Modern_Spanish n and ñ are considered different characters (rather than a character and an accented version of the same character).

Personally I'd stick with Latin1_General as changing the collation may subtly change the behavior of applications (e.g. yesterday this list was sorted one way, today it's sorted a different way, etc.). I'd only change the collation as part of the migration if you understand and want the behavior change.